# translate pseudocode palindrome

Tags: python, pseudocode

I have this pseudocode that I need to translate:

```
Prompt the user to enter a string and call it s.
Let l be the length of string
For i from 0 upto l-1:
    print s[0:i]
For i from 0 upto l-1:
    print s[i:l]
Print a closing statement
```

This is my translation:

```
 def main():

        s=(input("Please enter a string: "))
        L=len(s)

        for i in [0,L-1]:
            print (s[0:i])

        for i in [0,L-1]:
            print(s[i:L])

        print("This program is complete!")

    main()
```

However, the code isn't printing correctly. Can someone help me find my error? Thank you.

Comment: What does "isn't printing correctly" mean?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Could you include an example run that the program should model?

Comment: Justin, try using `for i in range(0, L-1):`. This could work better.

Answer (score 1):

You say `for i in [0,L-1]`, but `[0,L-1]` is a list with two elements: `0` and `L-1`.  What you want instead is `range(0, L)` or `range(L)`:

```
def main():

    s=(input("Please enter a string: "))
    L=len(s)

    for i in range(L):
        print (s[:i])

    for i in range(L):
        print(s[i:L])

    print("This program is complete!")

main()
```

Comment: Yeah just tried this, that works correctly.